# Correct word form

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following is correct and **why?**

- La ĉokolada kuko estas bongusta.
- La ĉokolado kuko estas bongusto.

Also, which is correct in the following:

- La kafo estas bongusto.
- La kafo estas bongusta.
- La kafo estas bonguston.

*In general, what rule must I follow to determine the right word form/ending?*

Answer (score 7):

The basic rule that you may be missing here is that the ending *-o* marks a noun and *-a* marks an adjective. An adjective is a word used to decribe a noun. Such as in “the red car”, the “red” is an adjective decribing the car. In Esperanto this would become *la ruĝa aŭto*. The *ruĝa* is describing the *aŭto*. In Esperanto you ĝenerally can’t put two nouns next to each other to describe something like *ruĝo aŭto*. Instead you either have to make one of them an adjective, or combine them into one word like *ruĝaŭto*.

- La ĉokolada kuko estas bongusta.

This sentence is correct and is a normal way to phrase it.

- La ĉokolado kuko estas bongusto.

This is not correct because it has the two nouns “ĉokolado kuko” together. You could potentially make them into one word like *ĉokoladokuko*, but in my opinion this sounds a bit clunky and it changes the meaning slightly.

- La kafo estas bongusto.

This sentence is grammatically correct but it probably doesn’t have the meaning you want. It would be like saying “the coffee is a good taste”, which just sounds odd.

- La kafo estas bongusta.

This is correct and is a normal way to phrase it.

- La kafo estas bonguston.

This is not correct. In general, *esti* does not take a *-n* ending, because it does not describe an action being done on something else so the accusative doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Dankon, @Neil Roberts, mi estas komencanto!